# multlined environment creates too much vertical space when used in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, mathtools

I would like to break my formula in a table into two lines. It seems good to use `multlined` environment. But the formula in table appears with a huge vertical space between two lines. The desired result should be like the formula under the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
$a=b$ & $c=d$ \\\hline
$x=y$ & $\begin{multlined}
    1+2+3+4+5+6\\
    +7+8+9+10+11=z
\end{multlined}$\\\hline
\end{tabular}

$\begin{multlined}
    1+2+3+4+5+6\\
    +7+8+9+10+11=z
\end{multlined}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd probably not use `multlined` (as I prefer aligned) but peace with that. Internally `multlined` uses a blank line after the first. This blank line is back up (negative space), but apparently the size of this has a different value inside table cells. A quick and dirty fix for your MWE is to add `\setlength\normallineskip{13pt}` to the start of the cell containing `multlined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

This is a bug known by the mathtools package authors.

Here is what is said in the documentation of mathtools, in the section "The multlined environment":

> Bug 1: If used inside an array or a derivative (say, a matrix variant), multlined does not work as expected. The implementation contains an ‘invisible’ line after the first multline row,  inside  an array this  line  is  no  longer  ‘invisible’  because array sets \baselineskip to zero. Currently we have no general workaround for this.
>
> Bug 2: [...] We have added a hook (\MultlinedHook) that can be added to. [...]

They also propose a code which fix the Bug 1:

```
\usepackage{mathtools,etoolbox}
\newlength\Normalbaselineskip
\setlength\Normalbaselineskip{\baselineskip}
\appto\MultlinedHook{\setlength\baselineskip{\Normalbaselineskip}}
```

I tried it and it did fix the bug.

### My opinion

Even though, I strongly suggest to avoid this kind of construction.
The use of single dollar signs means *inline* equation, which is opposite to what you want with the multlined environment.

Enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
a=b & c=d \\\hline
x=y & \begin{aligned}
    1+2+3+4+5+6\\
    +7+8+9+10+11=z
\end{aligned}\\\hline
\end{array}\]

\[\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
a=b & c=d \\\hline
x=y & \begin{aligned}
    1&+2+3+4+5+6\\
    &+7+8+9+10+11=z
\end{aligned}\\\hline
\end{array}\]

\[\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
a=b & c=d \\\hline
x=y & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{1+2+3+4+5+6}\\
    & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{+7+8+9+10+11=z}\\\hline
\end{array}\]

\end{document}
```